# Where to find .firebaserc file on mac?

Tags: firebase

I am new to programming and new to firebase as well. I have been trying to write firebase cloud function. I tested it successfully in development env and now I am trying to deploy in production env. In my case, both are different instances. I tried to re-initialize firebase thinking it will ask me to associate index.js to new DB but it skipped it. I understand that "DB" configuration is in .firebaseerc file. But I can't find it anywhere in my project directory. Anyone please help me?

Comment: Did you run `firebase init functions` from the command line?

Comment: On the cloud functions [Get Started guide](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/get-started#build_the_sample_in_your_firebase_project) it looks like `.firebaserc` gets generated automatically. If you're trying to find it in Mac Finder, make sure you have the option enabled to [show hidden files](https://ianlunn.co.uk/articles/quickly-showhide-hidden-files-mac-os-x-mavericks/).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[image]Your project folder that contains your "functions" folder will have the .firebaserc file in it.
On a MAC you can see the file by pressing Shift + Command + .(dot)

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't find the .firebaserc file but I did manage to solve problem but firiing firebase use --add command. Problem was solved.