# Where is firebaserc file on Linux Mint

Tags: firebase, debian-based

Where can I find `.firebaserc` file on Linux Mint in file browser? Or how to delete it using command line?

Comment: Possible duplicate https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990774/where-to-find-firebaserc-file-on-mac

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Where to find .firebaserc file on mac?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46990774/where-to-find-firebaserc-file-on-mac)

Answer (score 0):

Try to type in command line [CTRL + SHIFT + T]:

```
user@computer$ locate .firebaserc
```

The result should show absolute path to all matching files.